# Create custom article type with predefined fields in Joomla

Tags: joomla

i would like to create a custom article with predefined fields in that article so that the members of my site can create the content/article following the predefined fields. For example, "The Special Day in My Life" article will have following fields "Date, Image gallery, write-up, names, location(map)", certain fields are compulsory.

My site will then render all the content/articles in the same layout.

Is it possible to do so with Joomla? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is using one of the [content construction kits](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/) extensions you can find on the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/).

One of the most popular ones is [K2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/8061) but there are lots. You can find lots of [plug-ins that customise K2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/k2-extensions) even further also listed on the JED.

Answer (score 1):

I'd  Like to suggest Form2Content Component for Joomla 3.xx as it serves the purpose quite well.

Here are a few reasons why it is the best suitor.

- It creates articles with custom layout. The keyword here is
  "article", yup it creates Joomla articles but with a custom form with custom fields, the point I am trying to make is that since it creates native articles, all the content created by it enjoys all the **perks** like ...

  - SEO optimization
  - Page extension like ".html" if you are into such thingy
  - The Joomla! caching that would make a day and night difference once traffic
    is considerable etc.

  the same as any other article
- Front-end form (article) submission.
- Once you have the layout ready all it takes to create an article, is to fill out the form that you created and the articles are ready, no concern of a user/author messing the layout(maybe by forgetting a closing tag or whatever).
- Fully Integrated with Joomla! Tags Component.
- Lastly Its **FREE**! Well atleast the **lite version**. Though it still does the job, and you can always upgrade if you feel so.

[**JED Link**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/form2content-lite) || [**Website Link**](http://www.form2content.com/)

Comment: This tool is not supported any more for Joomla 4.0 and I found it very uncomfortable to use. Once created a new content type it cannot be changed any more.